# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, routes

I'm using angular 11 and I can't use any routing in my project, I have the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes 
. URL Segment: 'home/overview' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/overview'
```

I have several projects done this way and they worked fine,
This is the away I'm doing the routing:

```
import{Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { overviewComponent } from './home/overview/overview.component';



const routes: Routes = [

    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        children:[
   
            {
                path: 'overview',
                component: overviewComponent
             },
             {
                path: 'resources',
                component: HomeComponent
             },
             {
                path: 'facilities',
                component: HomeComponent
             },
             {
                path: 'research',
                component: HomeComponent
             },
             {
                path: 'fleet',
                component: HomeComponent
             },
             {
                path: 'defenses',
                component: HomeComponent
             },
             {
                path: 'universe',
                component: HomeComponent
             },
             {
               path: '',
               component: overviewComponent
            }
        ]

     },
     {
      path: '**',
      redirectTo: ''
   }
    
];

export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

If needed here is the rest of code:
https://bitbucket.org/ZeroD0Z/angularstratgamer/src/master/

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `AppRoutingModule` twice. Use `app-routing.module.ts` to define your routes instead of creating a custom file.

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [

    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    overviewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppRoutingModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```